# Sum of probabilities of all events less than 1?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I solved this question from the Bertsekas probability book:

On a given day, your golf score takes values uniformly from the range
101 to 110 (i.e. the probability of having a score of 101, 102, . . . 110 are
all 0.1), independent of other days. Determined to improve your score,
you decide to play on three different days and declare as your score the
minimum X of the scores X1, X2, and X3 on the different days. Calculate
the PMF and the expectation of X.

I have calculated the PMF of X as follows:

$P(X=x) = \frac{(111-x)^3-(110-x)^3}{1000}$

Now that I compute the exact value of probabilities for each $x=101,...,110$, the sum of all of these probabilities doesn't add up to 1.

Am I supposed to divide each probability by the sum of them?

Hypothetically, if the sum of the probabilities were 0.75 and P(X=101)=0.3, should I divide 0.3 by 0.7 to reach the correct probability of P(X=101)? Because this way, the sum of all probabilities will add up to 1.

Comment: your pmf is wrong, the sum is not only not equal to $1$ but is also way below three, please recheck your pmf.

Comment: Without commenting on whether the PMF is correct, when summed for $x = 101, \ldots, 110$ the probabilities add to $1$. ([WolframAlpha agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28111-x%29%5E3-%28110-x%29%5E3%29%2F1000%2C+x+from+101+to+110))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your PMF for $x = 101, \ldots, 110$, maybe you just had a mistake when adding those PMF for all $x$? Anyway here's my rework.

For each of $x = 101, \ldots, 110$, first consider the probability that $X$ is at least $x$:

$$\begin{align*}
P(X\ge x) &= P(\min(X_1, X_2, X_3)\ge x)\\
&= P(\{X_1\ge x\}\cap\{X_2\ge x\} \cap \{ X_3\ge x\})\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^3P(X_i\ge x)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^3 \frac{111-x}{10}\\
&= \frac{(111-x)^3}{1000}
\end{align*}$$

And also consider the probability that $X$ is strictly more than $x$:

$$\begin{align*}
P(X>x) &= P(X\ge x+1)\\
&= \begin{cases}\dfrac{(111-(x+1))^3}{1000}&x = 101,102,\ldots, 109\\
0&x= 110\end{cases}\\
&= \frac{(110-x)^3}{1000}
\end{align*}$$

So the PMF for $x = 101, \ldots, 110$, as you already found out, is

$$\begin{align*}
P(X=x) &= P(X\ge x) - P(X>x)\\
&= \frac{(111-x)^3 - (110-x)^3}{1000}
\end{align*}$$

As a check, the probability that $X$ is between $101$ and $110$ inclusive is

$$\begin{align*}
P(101\le X \le 110) &= \sum_{x=101}^{110}P(X=x)\\
&= \sum_{x=101}^{110} \frac{(111-x)^3 - (110-x)^3}{1000}\\
&= \frac{(10^3-9^3) + (9^3 - 8^3) + \cdots + (1^3 - 0^3)}{1000}\\
&= \frac{10^3 - 0^3}{1000}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you. I had a small mistake in my calculations as you said :)